# Xcode 5 crashes when exporting archive

Tags: crash, export, xcode5, archive, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to distribute my iOS app in OTA mode. It worked fine until now, but recently each time I try to export my archive, Xcode crashes.
I'm using OSX Mavericks and Xcode 5.0.2 (all are up to date).
Below is what I'm doing:

- Product -> Archive
- From the organizer -> Archives -> Distribute
- Save for Enterprise or ad-hoc deployment -> Click Next
- I select the provisioning profile (ad hoc profile) -> Click Export
- Here the finder appears and Xcode crashes.

I tried to repair disk permissions and read the forums for about 3 hours, still crashing !
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Best
Jerome

Comment: Ok, after some new research, found the answer from there: https://discussions.apple.com/message/23567487?tstart=0#23567487?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Go into the iOS developer centre and accept the new terms and conditions or licensing agreement.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue in both Xcode 6.0 & 6.1, I removed the account from Xcod Accounts & added it again, It worked like a charm